# pass an array of objects to a dropdown (select) using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass this array of objects

```
options = [
          {label:'React', value: 'react'},
          {label:'ReactNative', value: 'react-native'},
          {label:'JavaScript', value: 'js'},
          {label:'CSS', value: 'css'}        
        ];
```

to a select component

```
        <CustomSelect options={options} />
```

Nothing is taking the curly braces away.
I've tried:

```
         let options: { label: string, value: string}[] = [
           {label:'React', value: 'react'},
           {label:'ReactNative', value: 'react-native'},
           {label:'JavaScript', value: 'js'},
           {label:'CSS', value: 'css'}     
         ];
```

this is a type array with strings in it.

I've also tried:

```
    interface Option {
      label: string,
      value: string
    }
    
    let options: Option[] ;
    
    options = [
      {label:'React', value: 'react'},
      {label:'ReactNative', value: 'react-native'},
      {label:'JavaScript', value: 'js'},
      {label:'CSS', value: 'css'}
    
    ];
```

to create an object with strings in it.
My understanding is that I create an interface or a type to create an object?
Once I create an object, I need to define the array of strings and I don't know how to do that correctly in a typescript way.

Comment: what do you mean by `nothing is taking the curly braces away` ? I didn't understand what your problem is

Comment: Do you want to mutate your array of objects?

Comment: Your question is unclear. But I notice a typo in your example code. TypeScript types and interfaces should use a semicolon `;` to separate properties, not a comma `,`. This is part of what helps differentiate them from object values. Example: it should be `interface Option { label: string; value: string; }`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly from the question, you might need something like the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {options.map((options) => (
    <option key={options.label} value={options.value}>
      {options.label}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

If you want to make a custom dropdown component in typescript, this codesandbox might help

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rhodes-n6i8lc